# Search users within kilometers doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have script where I want to search users within given kilometers from specific city. User in database has city, longitude and latitude. User 1 has NYC, user 2 has Washington DC. I can give distance even 1000km and it doesn;t work. Why?

```
$user = User::with('user_data');
if ($request->has('city')) {
    $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) {
       return $query->where('residence', $request->city);
   });
}

if ($request->has('city')) {

    $latitude = app('geocoder')->geocode($request->city)->get()->first()->getCoordinates()->getLatitude(); 
    $longitude = app('geocoder')->geocode($request->city)->get()->first()->getCoordinates()->getLongitude();

    $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request, $latitude, $longitude) {

        return $query->whereRaw("( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( residence_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( residence_longitude ) - radians(".$longitude.") ) + sin ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( residence_latitude ) ) ) <= ". $request->distance .")");
   });
}
```

[image: DB]

[image: json]

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean, precisely? What goes wrong - an error? Incorrect calculation? Something else?

Comment: @ADyson i see user only from NYC, not also WDC

Comment: Without seeing the raw data in your database it's impossible to say whether the query is correct. But...your whereRaw seems to try and compare two values. I assume $request->distance is an value in km entered by you? What is the calculation on the left supposed to be outputting? Run it indepdenently - does it produce the value you expect?

Comment: When i write city it's ok, but with distance not. Yes, distance in km. @ADyson

Comment: I guess the calc is wrong, or the data is wrong. Like I said, we need to see the data really. Where did you get the formula for calculating this? Have you run the formula indepdently to see if it works as you expect? You didn't answer either of the questions in my last comment

Comment: What you need to see? @ADyson

Comment: the database data which you're trying to compare to, and the input data from the request you're using, and the result you're expecting. i.e. the same things anyone would need in order to test a function. Also please answer my questions regarding your distance-calculation formula (the bit on the left-side in the whereRaw clause).

Comment: @ADyson updated

Comment: Since you didn't answer re the formula I went and looked it up myself, and sure enough that's the problem - see my answer, which turned to be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your distance calculation formula is based on the Haversine formula.

We can start to test the distance calculation formula with the sample data provided.

```
SELECT ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(53.3364746) ) * cos( radians( 53.4285438 ) ) * cos( radians( 14.5528116 ) - radians(15.05037771) ) + sin ( radians(53.3364746) ) * sin( radians( 53.4285438 ) ) )
```

This returns

```
3534.1964590146517
```

(see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72188/8 )

According to the calculator provided by the National Hurricane Center website ( http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml ) the answer (rounded to the nearest whole number) should be:

```
35
```

So I think simply you need to add one more bit to your formular to divide your answer by 100, in order to get it in kilometres:

```
SELECT ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(53.3364746) ) * cos( radians( 53.4285438 ) ) * cos( radians( 14.5528116 ) - radians(15.05037771) ) + sin ( radians(53.3364746) ) * sin( radians( 53.4285438 ) ) ) / 100
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72188/9 for an updated version.

It now returns

```
35.34196459014652
```

which is the correct answer.

Translated to your PHP, you simply need to change one line as follows:

```
return $query->whereRaw("( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( residence_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( residence_longitude ) - radians(".$longitude.") ) + sin ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( residence_latitude ) ) ) / 100 <= ". $request->distance .")");
```

Comment: That's nice answer but my script returns user only from given city not location also.. check please my question I have two if's there. Maybe it is overriding? I need them two